.NET database-backed queues
I'm creating an API in .NET 8 for small uses and I need to implement 3 or 4 queues for long processing that don't depend on other systems besides its own database, like RabbitMQ.
I've only found the "DotnetWorkQueue" lib that implements this, but it has very simple documentation and for each queue it creates about 5 new tables, and there's no option to add an Oracle database.
So, I'm going to build my own queue structure to write to the database using EF Core.
I have a question about the consumer architecture.
Since it will be a long process (longer than 1 minute),
When the consumer starts processing, it will change the status to processing, but I also need to monitor whether it's still processing.
I thought about creating the consumers as Background Tasks and basically opening two threads, the main one that would execute the process and the second one to update a datetime field every 15 seconds.
Possible statuses:
Waiting
Processing
Completed
Error

Queue table:
Id
QueueName
Message
CreatedDateTime
LastHeartBeat

Is this correct, or is there a better way to implement it?
The idea later would be to document and make it public for more people who have this need.

"Tell, don't ask" - Polling has some disadvantages if the spirit of the application is event-driven (like the event of "Processing finished"). So, you might consider an architecture where you can push, rather than poll.

@Fildor I need this data in a database to perform audits, for this reason I thought about queues, for example a process to generate large files, I can know, if the application crashed or restarted, I can restart the process.

Maybe our definitions of the term "queue" is different but how would a queue fit in there? Sounds more like a db-backed state machine.

For me, even driven would be a way to directly call events, without mediation and auditing with a database for history and logs. The queue would occur by reading the database as new records appear. The idea would be to separate the application into 2 monoliths, the core part, synchronous, and the other, the workers separately for asynchronous processing. Does it make sense to use even driven instead of pub/sub queues here? using events, if the application crashes, wouldn't it start processing again when it comes back online?
